# How to write proper syntax for dimensional formula

Tags: pdftex

I am writing a report using Texmaker, and I had to arrange the dimensional formula for different physical quantities in a table. I am having a problem regarding the proper syntax to write for example ML^2/T^2. I noticed that T^2 is written italic and not in a professional way. I searched a lot but didn't reach to the right syntax. Can anyone please help me with the proper way to write this. Thank you in advance.

```
Force & 1/ N^{2} & ML/T^{2} \\
    Energy & 1/ N^{3}  & ML^{2}/T^{2} \\
    Flexural rigidity & 1/N^{4} & ML^{3}/T^{2} \\
```

[image: This is the output for the quantities in the third column.]

[image: Ths is one of the error messages showed up after compiling the latex code]

Comment: Define `professional way` and explain what N, M, L and T are in this case?

Comment: it seems unlikey that the fragment shown produced the output shown with no error messages. If column 3 is math mode ML would be italic, if it is text the `^`  would give an error. For _any_ error the pdf output is not intended to be usable, and you should ask about the error message, not about the output

Comment: Without the working code, it's hardly possible to hep. Can you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)?

Comment: Maybe the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package can help?

Comment: @daleif M - mass, L - length, T - time (don't know what N is)

Comment: When building the latex file, this is one of the many error messages showed on the screen. I am not sure if this related to the format of the output form.

Comment: `^` requires math mode (here `$...$`)

Comment: @daleif Thanks so much. This fixes my issue. Much appreciated to all of you guys.